# unexpected behaviour parsing xml with SAXParser

Tags: java, parsing, sax

I am simply reading an xml and writing back the xml:

```
<p>Il <b>1888</b> (MDCCCLXXXVIII in numeri romani) è un anno bisestile del XIX secolo.</p>
```

The result is:

```
<p>Il<b>1888</b> (MDCCCLXXXVIII in numeri romani) è un anno bisestile del XIX secolo.</p>
```

As you can see I have lost a space.

Can someone explain me why, or how can I prevent this ?

My code:

```
 package parsing;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class TextCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = "<p>Il <b>1888</b> (MDCCCLXXXVIII in numeri romani) è un anno bisestile del XIX secolo.</p>";
        String newString = readSave(text);
        System.out.println(newString);

    }

    public static String readSave(String text) throws Exception {


        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream((text).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document document = saxBuilder.build(is);
        Element classElement = document.getRootElement();

        //processElement(classElement, months, monthIndex);

        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getCompactFormat().setOmitDeclaration(true));
        String output = outputter.outputString(classElement);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Format.getCompactFormat()` looks like it's probably the culprit. It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] and mention that you're using JDom...

Comment: I adjusted the question, I added the complete minimal code to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Format.getRawFormat()` instead of `Format.getCompactFormat()`

Format.getCompactFormat()

```
<p>Il<b>1888</b>(MDCCCLXXXVIII in numeri romani) è un anno bisestile del XIX secolo.</p>
```

Format.getPrettyFormat()

```
<p>
  Il
  <b>1888</b>
  (MDCCCLXXXVIII in numeri romani) è un anno bisestile del XIX secolo.
</p>
```

Format.getRawFormat()

```
<p>Il <b>1888</b> (MDCCCLXXXVIII in numeri romani) è un anno bisestile del XIX secolo.</p>
```